# Typescript compile error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for '.svn'

Tags: visual-studio, typescript, svn, msbuild, tsc

I've been having an issue when trying to compile typescript. tsc.exe gives the following error:

error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for '.svn'.

SVN is being used for source control and it looks like its trying to compile items in the .svn folder. I cannot figure out why it is doing this.

The compiler points at the a tsconfig.json file with the following content:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noEmitOnError": false,
    "removeComments": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "module" : "none"
  },
  "include": [
    "../../jquery.d.ts",
    "./**/*"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "wwwroot"
  ]
}
```

I have tried explicitly excluding the .svn folder in tsconfig but it still generates the same error. I have even tried removing the .svn folder from the directory where my typescript files are and still it gives the error.

I have also done a repair on visual studio and Typescript tools and resinstalled both to no avail.

I cannot find references to .svn in either the project or any of the TypeScript.target file.

This all works fine on colleagues machines and I have the exact same setup so I really don't understand where the error is coming from.

I am running V2.2.2 of typescript and Visual Studio 2015 update 3.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. This has been driving me insane for days now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I encountered the same error message. I solved it by upgrading my Subversion client to version 1.7. Subversion 1.7 is different from earlier versions in that it uses only one .svn folder at the top rather than one in each folder. If your top folder under Subversion control does not have any Typescript files, as is my situation, then I think this will work for you. By the way, I encountered this problem using Jenkins to run the Typescript compiler. I fixed the problem by configuring Jenkins to use Subversion 1.7 instead of an earlier version.

Comment: Upgraded my SVN Client and it all works !!! Thank you so much for this, I can't tell you how long I spent trying to solve this !